# hook_entity_presave() doesn't work

Tags: 8, hooks

I want to save some details before saving the node, and I tried with `hook_node_presave()`.

```
function hook_node_presave(Drupal Core Entity EntityInterface $node) {
  if ($node->id() && $node->moderate) {
    // Reset votes when node is updated:
    $node->score = 0;
    $node->users = '';
    $node->votes = 0;
  }
}
```

Then with `hook_entity_presave()`.

```
function hook_entity_presave(Drupal Core Entity EntityInterface $entity) {
  $entity->changed = REQUEST_TIME;
}
```

Both hooks don't work. Why?

Comment: If those are the function names you really used, they aren't considered hooks, except in the case the machine name of the module is hook.

Comment: When asking about code you are using, you should show the real code you are using, or it gets harder to answer the question, Also, you could know it, but it would not be the first time users make a _typo_ like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
function mymodule_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getEntityType()->id() == 'node') {
    $entity->setTitle('The new Title');
    //CAUTION : Do not save here, because it's automatic.
  }
}
```

http://drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/65/update-a-node-entity-programmatically-drupal-8

Comment: hook_entity_presave() is not working on my site. I am using hook_node_presave() function. Don't know what's the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Your function should be named according to your module's name. If your module is called "foo", then:

```
function foo_node_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node) {
```

Note also the use of backslashes, not spaces, to separate namespaces.

Comment: Yes i have done like that !

Comment: @IcecreamJelly I see spaces in the namespace, so the answer given here is correct. If you don't show the code you are using, in a question about code, or the shown code contains typos, don't expect a different answer.